# The type 'RPC' is not a valid attribute

Tags: rpc

i try to develop a new multiplayer game in unity and i have a problem to make work The RPC function. 
and i get the error
Assets/RPC.js(25,2): BCE0033: The type 'RPC' is not a valid attribute.
were this line is the @RPC
Its seams i missing something

this is my code

```
var cube : GameObject;
var nView: NetworkView;
function Start() {
nView = GetComponent.<NetworkView>();
}
 function Update () {

}



function OnGUI(){
if (GUI.Button(Rect(100,200,100,40), "Make a Cube")) {

    var viewID : NetworkViewID= Network.AllocateViewID();

    nView.RPC("MakeCube", 
                    RPCMode.AllBuffered, 
                    viewID, 
                    transform.position);
}

}

@RPC
function MakeCube(){
Instantiate(cube, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: What Unity version are you using here? JS files were made obsolete years ago (along with previous networking stacks)

Comment: @AndrewŁukasik tank you for replay after a few weeks with out net i was only able to read today , after see your comment i decide to do it in c# and i get it work

Comment: I suggest you use VIS2K's "Mirror" for easy networking. You can download it from asset store page here: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/mirror-129321 . It's very similar to Unet but better.